# Compress muliple images from JPG to PNG

Tags: flutter, dart

I have done a single image selected from gallery conversion from JPG to PNG now I want to convert multiple images selected from the gallery below is the code for single image conversion

```
 getImages() async {
     var _image;
     // Use the getImage() method from the image_picker package
     final _pickedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     final pickedFile = decodeImage(File(_pickedImage.path).readAsBytesSync());

     setState(()async {
       if (pickedFile != null) {

         final output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

         var destination = '${output.path}/test_image$index.png';
         index = index + 1;
         // Convert your image to PNG using the encodePng method from the image package
         _image = File(destination)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(pickedFile));
         print("_image");
         GallerySaver.saveImage(_image.path, albumName: 'Image Resizer')
             .then((bool success) {
           Fluttertoast.showToast(
               msg: "Image saved",
               toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
               gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
               timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
               backgroundColor: Colors.red,
               textColor: Colors.white,
               fontSize: 16.0);
         });
         print(_image.toString());
       } else {
         print('No image selected.');
       }
       return _image;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can try to use [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) plugin for it.

Comment: I used that but what I should pass in place of  pickedFile in this line        _image = File(destination)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(pickedFile));

Comment: Pass it in `for` loop and manage compression for each file.

Comment: used that also @fartem

Comment: @JanviPatel What was the problem when you tried a `for` loop?

Comment: @AliAlizadeh it is solved now